# Catch exceptions caused by dynamic SQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

I have a stored procedure which calls another stored procedure using dynamic SQL. A simplified version of the code is provided here.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`cmdb`@`%` PROCEDURE `testCall`(procName VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN

   DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION 
   BEGIN

       GET DIAGNOSTICS @num = NUMBER;
       GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION @num @message = MESSAGE_TEXT, @errNo = RETURNED_SQLSTATE ;
       if @errorMessage is null then
           Set @errorMessage = "No Error Message";
       end if;
       select @errorMessage;
   END;
   select concat("call ", procName, "()") into @proc;
   Prepare stmt FROM @proc;
   Execute stmt;
   deallocate prepare stmt;
END
```

If intent is to call an arbitrary stored procedure using testCall. When I call testCall with a non-existent SP name as input as following,

```
call testCall("storedProc4");
```

I see the following error message:

```
"No Error Message"
```

I expect to see something like below:

```
"PROCEDURE storedproc4 does not exist"
```

How to catch this exception? I have tried a CONTINUE handler for error 1305 and an EXIT handler as well with the similar results.

Comment: `if @errorMessage is null then` ... where in this code do you actually set a variable called `@errorMessage`?  I see only `@message`.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that! I have looked at the code a hundred times!